# how to find $E\left[ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}V_n\mid X_0=i \right]$ where $T = \min\{t>0: X_t = i\}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ is an irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent Markov Chain with state space $S$ and stationary distribution $\pi$. Suppose that $V_n$ are random variables with the property that
$$E[V_n\mid X_n=i_0, \ldots, X_n = i_n] = f(i_n), \forall n, i_0, \ldots, i_n, $$
for some function $f(\cdot)$.

Fix $i \in S$ and let $T = \min\{t>0: X_t  = i\}$. Derive an expression for
$$E\left[ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}V_n\mid X_0=i \right]. $$

Hint: $\pi_j = \frac{E\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1} 1_{X_n=j}\mid X_0=i\right] }{E[T\mid X_0=i]}=\frac{E\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 1_{X_n=j} 1_{T>n} \mid X_0=i\right] }{E[T \mid X_0=i]}$.

---

Firstly, we know $E[T\mid X_0 = i] = \frac{1}{\pi_i}$, then $E\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1} 1_{X_n=j}\mid X_0=i \right] = \frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}$.

Since $E[V_n\mid X_0=i_0, \ldots, X_n=i_n] = f(i_n)$, I think $$E\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1}V_n\mid X_0=i\right] = \sum\limits_{j \in S} f(j)^{E\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^{T-1} 1_{X_n=j}\mid X_0=i \right]} = \sum\limits_{j \in S}f(j)^{\frac{\pi_j}{\pi_i}}.$$

But I am not sure about it.  Also I have no idea why we need to study such kind of problem since it's a little confusing to introduce $V_n$.